# rails db:migrate giving warning and not creating any table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ubuntu, migrate, sqlite3-ruby

When I start doing code on (see image below) rails I saw rails guide to getting start with it. There's a command rails `db:migrate` for creating table and stuff. But its giving only warning and not creating any table.

[image: Example]

Comment: Hi. In fact, your screenshot clearly states that there are warnings, but also the migration did run through and create an articles table.

Comment: then what is meaning of these warning?

Comment: You're using deprecated methods. That can be due to outdated gems or your code isn't up to date with the gem version you are using.

Comment: thank you soo much for help

Answer (score 0):

The code has executed successfully and there are no issues with it. The warnings are because either your code, or some of the gems you  have used in the code contain some methods that are deprecated. 
If the warning comes  from your code, try to fix them. If it is from any dependency, then watch for updates, keep the gems updated, or you can also write to the gem developer to fix these warnings.